# One if statement halting progress

Tags: php, mysql

I am having trouble with some if statements. To cut a long story short, when a certain statement is true, the code stops and doesn't move on to the next loop/series of if statements.

Here is the first statement that once reached, doesn't move on.

```
else if ((($pteam_score[$i] == $popposition_score[$i]) && ($pteam_score[$i] != 0) &&     ($popposition_score[$i] != 0))) {

$team_points[$i]-=2;
$opposition_points[$i]-=2;
$team_win[$i]-=0;
$team_draw[$i]-=1;
$team_loss[$i]-=0;
$team_extra[$i]-=0;

$opp_win[$i]-=0;
$opp_draw[$i]-=1;
$opp_loss[$i]-=0;
$opp_extra[$i]-=0;

$played[$i]-=1;
echo "hey";
$query9=$database->query("UPDATE results_a SET team_name='$team[$i]',     team_score='$pteam_score[$i]',
opposition_score='$popposition_score[$i]', opposition_name='$opposition[$i]' where     fixture_id='$fixture_id'");

}
```

And here is the second. Bare in mind there are about 20 of these ifs/else ifs/ and when any of the others are hit, the points are decucted (as they are with the two bad loops also) butit seems it doesn't then move on to a separate section of the code. Perhaps coincidentally, both bad loops involve a draw result!

```
    else if ((($pteam_score[$i] == $popposition_score[$i]) && ($pteam_score[$i] != 0) &&     ($popposition_score[$i] != 0))) {

$team_points[$i]-=2;
$opposition_points[$i]-=2;
$team_win[$i]-=0;
$team_draw[$i]-=1;
$team_loss[$i]-=0;
$team_extra[$i]-=0;

$opp_win[$i]-=0;
$opp_draw[$i]-=1;
$opp_loss[$i]-=0;
$opp_extra[$i]-=0;

$played[$i]-=1;
echo "what?";
$query9=$database->query("UPDATE results_a SET team_name='$team[$i]',     team_score='$pteam_score[$i]',
opposition_score='$popposition_score[$i]', opposition_name='$opposition[$i]' where     fixture_id='$fixture_id'");

}
```

Can anybody see any reason the code would stop dead with the above two statements? The echo stuff is just to see which option is hit. As I said, these two loops are hit at the correct times, but they are the only two that seem to stop the process.

EDIT - A SECTION THAT WORKS FINE

```
if (($team_score[$i] == $pteam_score[$i]) && ($opposition_score[$i] ==     $popposition_score[$i])) {
$team_points[$i]+=0;
$opposition_points[$i]+=0;
$team_win[$i]+=0;
$team_draw[$i]+=0;
$team_loss[$i]+=0;
$team_extra[$i]+=0;

$opp_win[$i]+=0;
$opp_draw[$i]+=0;
$opp_loss[$i]+=0;
$opp_extra[$i]+=0;

$played[$i]+=0;

echo "0";
$query11=$database->query("UPDATE results_a SET team_name='$team[$i]',     team_score='$pteam_score[$i]',
opposition_score='$popposition_score[$i]', opposition_name='$opposition[$i]' where      fixture_id='$fixture_id'");

}
else if (($pteam_score[$i] == 0) && ($popposition_score[$i] == 0)) {
$team_points[$i]+=0;
$opposition_points[$i]+=0;
$team_win[$i]+=0;
$team_draw[$i]+=0;
$team_loss[$i]+=0;
$team_extra[$i]+=0;

$opp_win[$i]+=0;
$opp_draw[$i]+=0;
$opp_loss[$i]+=0;
$opp_extra[$i]+=0;

$played[$i]+=0;
echo "bla";

}
 if (($pteam_score[$i] != $team_score[$i]) && ($popposition_score[$i] ==     $opposition_score[$i])) {


  if (($pteam_score[$i] > $popposition_score[$i]) && ($pteam_bonus[$i] >     $popposition_score[$i])) {
$team_points[$i]-=3;
$opposition_points[$i]-=0;
$team_win[$i]-=1;
$team_draw[$i]-=0;
$team_loss[$i]-=0;
$team_extra[$i]-=0;

$opp_win[$i]-=0;
$opp_draw[$i]-=0;
$opp_loss[$i]-=1;
$opp_extra[$i]-=0;

$played[$i]-=1;
echo "6";
$query5=$database->query("UPDATE results_a SET team_name='$team[$i]',     team_score='$pteam_score[$i]',
opposition_score='$popposition_score[$i]', opposition_name='$opposition[$i]' where     fixture_id='$fixture_id'");

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'll keep my mental clothes on, thanks.

Comment: I assume `$i` is increased elsewhere?

Comment: yes it is,but once this option is true, the next section of code doesn't  run

Comment: Considering the lack of detail, you may want to at least add a working section of the code to compare to.

Comment: The first and second have the same condition; combined with `else` the second will not be called. But I guess that is because of the code snippets. Restructuring the code, simplifying might help. And then there is the obligatory pointer to better using a Prepared Statement.